# Creating a button with swt.arrow and image

Tags: java, swt

I'd like to create a button like the one represented in the figure [image] to my Eclipse RCP applications editor part. Currently I can only have one of the images (add or arrow). Is there some easy way to have both of the images in one button?

```
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    ...
    Button btn = new Button(btnCntrl, SWT.FLAT|SWT.ARROW|SWT.DOWN);
    btn.setImage(Activator.getImageDescriptor("platform:/plugin/com.famfamfam.silk/icons/add.png").createImage());
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SWT `Button` can only have either an arrow or text and/or image. To emulate an image button with a drop-down arrow you may want to use a toolbar with a tool button.

For Example:

```
ToolBar toolbar = new ToolBar( parent, SWT.NONE );
ToolItem button = new ToolItem( toolBar, SWT.DROP_DOWN );
button.setImage( ... );
```

Comment: Thank you! I somehow passed this option as I read that you can't have toolbars in `EditorPart`, but of course you can if you add them manually!